# bosh_cli gem conflicts with other version

Tags: rubygems, cf-bosh, bosh-deployer

I was using bosh_cli version 1.3071.0 and recently I installed latest version of bosh_cli 1.3262.4.0.

Now when launch bosh command it is giving

```
ubuntu@vik-test-inception:~/.gem/specs$ bosh --version
Failed to load plugin /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/bosh_cli_plugin_micro-1.3071.0/lib/bosh/cli/commands/micro.rb: Unable to activate bosh_cli_plugin_micro-1.3071.0, because bosh_common-1.3262.4.0 conflicts with bosh_common (~> 1.3071.0), blobstore_client-1.3262.4.0 conflicts with blobstore_client (~> 1.3071.0), bosh_cli-1.3262.4.0 conflicts with bosh_cli (~> 1.3071.0)
```

What is the way to upgrade existing gem of a app to latest version so that it won't conflict.

Comment: Can you try `gem uninstall bosh_cli --all` then `gem install bosh_cli`? I'd also recommend upgrading your Ruby version as 1.9.3 has been EOL for almost two years.

Answer (score 1):

I had faced same issue and solved by uninstalling the version which doesn't have dependency.

Below command will list of all version:

```
gem uninstall bosh_cli
```

Choose the version, which doesn't have dependency.